# Copy file from S3 to EBS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I have to write a python script which will copy a file in s3 to my EBS directory, here the problem is I'm running this python script from my local machine. is there any boto function in which I can copy from s3 to EBS without storing in my local?

Comment: Assuming that you are talking about EBS volumes, EBS volumes are attached to EC2 instances. Why don't you simply run your script on that EC2 instance? Also, unless you specifically have to do this in Python, you should consider using the awscli to download files from S3.

Answer (score 3):

No. EBS volumes are accessible only on the EC2 instance they're mounted on. If you want to download a file directly from S3 to an EBS volume, you need to run your script on the EC2 instance.